# SQL transform two records into two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, split, pivot

I don´t know if the title is correct but basicaly I need this(result of query):

```
r_e_s_id  person_id
89074      161704
89074      161703
89095      161708
89095      161707
68651      129884
68651      129883
81512      161074
81512      161073
```

To be inserted/updated(in case that there will be r_e_s_id values in table) into table COMM_PROP which has cols - r_e_s_id, perid1, perid2...like this:

```
r_e_s_id   perid1   perid2
89074      161704   161703
89095      161708   161707
68651      129884   129883
81512      161074   161073
```

How can I do this? I´m using Oracle 11g.

Thank you for any help!!!

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: If not as different column, then you cpuld use string aggreagation techniques. There are several ways depending on your version. But, if you want it to be a different column, then you need UNPIVOT. But, as @bluefeet said, you need to tell us the version.

Comment: @BohuslavDvorský Will you only ever have 2 `perid` values?  Or will it be unknown?

Comment: @bluefeet I'm guessing unknown because of the ellipses while describing the result columns. 
"r_e_s_id, perid1, perid2..."

Comment: @ruudvan That'd be my guess too, but it'd be better to be confirmation from the OP.  Dynamic SQL pivoting in oracle is not very easy.

Comment: I will always have 2 perid values. I´m sure of that because of query that return my resuld set

Comment: I think this is not a pivot case, you don't want to convert rows in columns, you want max and min of a column, as Ankit is showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering only 2 values i.e. 1 max and 1 min per r_e_s_id, Try this:-

```
 SELECT r_e_s_id, MAX(person_id) AS  perid1, MIN(person_id) AS perid2
 FROM YOUR_TABLE
 GROUP BY r_e_s_id;
```

Comment: I didn't understand the vote down. I think this is a possible solution.

Comment: Not my vote, but what happens if they have more than two values?  This wouldn't work

Comment: Thats y i have written `Considering only 2 values i.e. 1 max and 1 min per r_e_s_id`................. and which is clearly visible from the Sample as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This actualy works. If Anyone know the solution for multiple values - more than two...I would be glad to hear that as well :-)